# Cant run a process with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a command to run from python program

```
python test.py arg1 arg2
```

If I run it using

```
os.system("python test.py arg1 arg2")
```

it runs.

I want to use subprocess.Popen() but when I do that

```
subprocess.Popen("python test.py arg1 arg2")
```

It gives the following error

```
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If argument to `Popen` is a string, it tries to execute it as `'sh <argument>'`, so in your case it becomes `'sh python test.py arg1 arg2'` that is obviously wrong.  You can pass it a list (as twall suggested), or specify `shell=True` parameter.  The next should work:

```
subprocess.Popen("python test.py arg1 arg2", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

try putting all your arguments in a list:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py", "arg1", "arg2"])
```

see: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: thanks for your answer... It works... but the one above suits my requirement the best